# How to use HTML or CSS to style an info window in Google Fusion Tables?

Tags: html, css, google-fusion-tables, styling, infowindow

I have created a KML map and uploaded to Fusion Tables where I am trying to customise the info box through their HTML code box. The info box contains a simple table with text and figures. Here is the code:

```
<div class="googft-info-window"
style="background-color:red"
{description}
</div>
```

The info-window background will change colour to red, but the table does not (which is the {description} in the code above.

Is there a way to style the table? I essentially want to change the color of the tables text but not the headings in the info window!

Answer (score 1):

If that's your entire code, then it's not proper HTML – you're missing your closing div bracket ">", I assume before {description} and after "red". I'm assuming that's just a typo when you wrote the question.

You can always wrap your {description} in it's own div and apply styles to that. So an example code is:

```
<div class='googft-info-window' style='width: 500px;'>
  <div style='background-color: red; overflow: auto;'>
     {description}
  </div>
</div>
```

I included "overflow: auto;" so the div will expand to fit your content. If you'd like it to expand just one direction, do "overflow-y: auto" or overflow-x: auto;". You can do as much formatting as needed.

That should hopefully help out some. I apologize if I completely missed the point of your question.

I've gone a few steps further below if you or others are interested.

---

### Dynamic Templates

You can even go a step or two further and add conditional formatting based on items in the row, but that requires a bit more coding. You can change the style of specific elements based on your information.

Let's say you have a table with 3 columns, it could look like this:

```
<div class='googft-info-window' style='width: 520px;'>
  <table style='background-color: red; overflow: auto; margin: 10px;'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style='width: 100px;'>Term</th>
        <th style='width: 300px;'>Name</th>
        <th style='width: 100px;'>Party</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{term}</td>
        <td>{first_name} {last_name}</td>
        <td>{party}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </div>
</div>
```

With conditional formatting/dynamic templating, you can make your table (or whatever element you'd like) a different style. In this example, the background color of the entire table will be dependent on which political party the person in that row belongs to:

```
{template .contents}
    <div class='googft-info-window' style='width: 520px;'>
    {if $data.formatted.party=='Republican'}
      <table style='background-color: lightcoral; overflow: auto; margin: 10px;'>
    {else}
    {if $data.formatted.party=='Democrat'}
      <table style='background-color: lightskyblue; overflow: auto; margin: 10px;'>
    {else}
      <table style='background-color: white; overflow: auto; margin: 10px;'>
    {/if}{/if}
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style='width: 100px;'>Term</th>
            <th style='width: 300px;'>Name</th>
            <th style='width: 100px;'>Party</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{$data.formatted.term}</td>
            <td>{$data.formatted.first_name} {$data.formatted.last_name}</td>
            <td>{$data.formatted.party}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </div>
</div>
{/template}
```

Notice in the above example, it is wrapped in "{template .contents}" and "{/template}". To do dynamic formatting, {template} ... {/template} are required, but .contents is not. Each field within needs to have {$data.formatted.[field_name]} where [field_name] would be replaced with your fields. Once you wrap your content with {template}, if you click the fields on the left, they will be added in the correct formatting wherever your cursor is placed within the text box.

More information on [Dynamic Templating](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/3081246?hl=en&ref_topic=2575652) and [Closures](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/concepts#filestructure).